# Encrypting retrieved data from Selenium/Watir

Tags: java, ruby, encryption, selenium, watir

When using Selenium (or Watir) as a Web data extractor, is there a way to encrypt each circulating flow between Websites and extractor in order to avoid any kind of "man-in-the-middle" attacks?

Comment: Isn't that what https is for?

Comment: Creating a Tunnel SSH between server and client hosts might be a good solution...